# Get body before domready?

Tags: javascript, domready

```
<html>
<head>
<script>alert(document.body.className);</script>
</head>
<body>
something
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this code may return a classname of the body.

But instead, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null`

Is there some way to get and set classname of the body in head before `domready` event?

The only way is to append this code to `domready` event?

Comment: ...Your javascript isn't even wrapped in `<script></script>` tags...how is that even executing?

Comment: in fact it's wrapped, forgot to add this to an example.

Comment: When the `<head>` is being processed, and the JavaScript being executed, the `<body>` tag hasn't been reached yet so it won't know what the class is supposed to be.

Comment: Documents are loaded from the top down, so if your Javascript runs before the body tag has been processed, then it won't know that Body exists. You can either place your code inside of the body tag, or you can hook the dom ready event.

Comment: the nearest event to get body's class is domready?

Comment: @JohnRezza If you want to keep the `<script>` tag inside the `<head>`, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with JavaScript. You can't access document.body until the body element exists. It does not exist until virtually the entire page is rendered (because the closing  is the second last tag on any page)